# Is there any difference between controlled vs uncontrolled and statefull vs stateless components?

Tags: reactjs, components, stateless, conceptual, stateful

I am curious whether there is any difference when we try to differentiate react components as controlled vs uncontrolled and stateful vs stateless. Are we differentiating the same thing here with different terminologies or is there an actual difference when we distinguish in such a way? I am beginning to suspect there are subtle changes but cannot wrap my head around them. If there are no differences please provide a brief explanation as to why such a reasoning is invalid. If there are please explain the differences no matter how minute they may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in a few cases, these terminologies might mean the same, there is actually a difference between them

**controlled vs uncontrolled** is basically used to specify whether the view or the state of the component can be controlled from within itself or from outside.

**stateless vs statefull** is used to describe whether the component contains state or not. A controlled component can also contain a state. In React generally a stateless component is written as a Functional component which is `View` only component but can also be written as a Class component making use of lifecycle method/or not

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation. I guess this somewhat clears the doubt that I had. Would it be possible for you to provide a scenario wherein one would prefer controlled components over just designing a stateful components? I just want to know the use cases here.